# Program prints only lines from zombie process

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, fork

I have the following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main() {
    int p, i;
    p=fork();
    if (p == -1) {perror("fork() error "); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    if (p == 0) { 
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            printf("Child: i=%d pid=%d, ppid=%d\n", i, getpid(), getppid());
        exit(0);
    } else { 
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("Parent: i=%d pid=%d ppid=%d\n", i, getpid(), getppid());
        wait(0); 
    }
}
```

If the parent process decides not to wait for child process ( delete the line which contains wait(0) statement), on the terminal will be printed only those lines within the child process. If I choose to redirect the output of the program  into an arbitrary file ( that would be: ./source_code > some_file), some_file file will contain lines from parent process and child process, not only from child process like above. How is this possible?

Comment: I can't replicate your behavior, Even when removing the `wait(NULL)` call both the parent and child output is written, as it should. Please don't forget the ***Verifiable*** part of your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please show us the expected and actual output of your program.

Comment: Terminal is slow when compared to file io. Mixing non synchronized output from more than on process/thread on the terminal can lead to quasi garbage.

Comment: If you run it enough number of times, you __might__ see some output in the terminal case too.